# mint - change spare storage drive's UUID to something human-friendly

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk

For noobs struggling with their migration from macOS or Windows...

By default, when formatting and partitioning a new drive, Linux will assign a UUID to the drive, however, this UUID now shows up in programs and is not human-friendly.

How may I make the drive identifiers human-readable?

Answer (score 0):

To change the UUID to something for humans, use the "Disks" utility, and edit the mount options as follows:

[image]

- Set "Display Name" to the name you want (e.g. your_name) (don't use spaces, kiss).
- Replace the UUID in the "Mount point" with the your_name... (but keep the /mnt/)
- Set the "Identify as" to the item that reads LABEL=your_name

[image]

Comment: Please note this is not changing the drives UUID as the question asks but setting a label on the drive. That is much safer than what the question asks for as it doesn't increase the chance of ID collision with other drives.